# Capturing 23 packets in udp 53 port

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, udp, telnet, wireshark

I am using wireshark to capture packets from udp.port == 53.

when I do "ping Domain" name.. I can capture 2 packets on the udp.port == 53.

when I do the same ping I don't capture any thing where I have to change the domain name in order to capture packets.

Why that is happening, or what is actually happening, why I do capture them in the first place  ???

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you `ping Domain` and capture packets and then `ping Domain` and don't capture packets. "I have to change the domain name in order to capture packets" => you can capture packets again using `ping XXXXXX`. It sounds like your computer caching DNS lookups, which is just fine. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live

Comment: Great answer but why the 53 port can capture the 23 packets?

Comment: could you please explain more to me about caching DNS lookups I read the things in the link but i didnt understand well

Comment: What 23 packets?  Your question says nothing about 23 packets, just about 2 packets.

Answer (score 2):

The first time you do "ping {domain name}", if the system doesn't have the IP address for {domain name} cached, it'll send a DNS request to look it up and get back a DNS response, the first one going to port 53 and the second one coming from port 53.

When that first DNS lookup is done, the resolver will cache the results, so that subsequent attempts to look up {domain name} will *not* do a DNS lookup - they'll just return the results of the previous DNS lookup - and will thus happen faster and cause less network traffic and less load on the DNS server.  It will not remember the results forever, because the IP address for that host name might change; the results of the lookup have a "time-to-live", and, after that time expires, the cached results will be discarded and a new DNS lookup will be done.

See [the "Record Caching" section of the Wikipedia page for DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Record_caching).